# Why state is null in the first render - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, state

In the first render state is null and I need to put a condition. Is this how reactjs work or I am doing sth wrong?

Code link: https://jsfiddle.net/taimoor7/6o31k2ay/4/

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  Constructor(props){
    Super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: false }
  }
  render() {
    console.log("this.state", this.state)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello Reactjs</h1>
        <button>
          {this.state.isToggleOn? 'ON': 'OFF'}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const element = (<Toggle />);
const rootEle = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(element, rootEle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in your constructor:

```
Constructor(props){
    Super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: false }
  }
```

1. Change `Constructor` to `constructor` the SMALL `c`.
2. Change `Super` to `super`, the SMALL `s`.

Use code below:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: false }
  }
```

Comment: thanks @Abhay infact I came after two months to reactjs. I was doing some practice on jsfiddle and stuck with this thing..........

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: false }
  }
```